# What is the meaning of Catchable fatal error in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php 
    $category-name = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'wiki_test_taxonomy_radio',true);
    echo get_the_category_by_ID( $category-name[0] ); 
?>
```

when i write this code and then it shows the problem.

Comment: Please add error text here.

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in D:\back up file\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\paintrepublic\test.php on line 63

Comment: Try the solution which i answered

Comment: i try that but it don't work

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
<?php 
    $category_name = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'wiki_test_taxonomy_radio',true);
    echo get_the_category_by_ID( $category_name ); 
?>
```

It will remove capchable fatel error. But if you not get any result then try to

echo $category_name; or

print_r($category_name);

Hope it will work

Comment: Did you try to echo $category_name' or print_r($category_name)'. Try this and let me know the output of this

Comment: Also you need to pass $cat_ID in place to $category_name; something like this              get_the_category_by_ID( $cat_ID );

Comment: none of those work.dada .By the way i am developing cmb2 plugin of field's array type 'taxonomy_radio'.The actual problem is i did'nt print the category name.The  code i am writing describe above.i tried all of your suggestion.but it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try This**

```
$category_name = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'wiki_test_taxonomy_radio',true);
echo get_the_category_by_ID( $category_name );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this

Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/greg2205/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 433
 then try this .

Go to your **WordPress database** 
Then table **wp_posts**,
if you view the content of the table by **post_type** you will see all of the **nav_menu_items** grouped together.

Now you need to delete the right row from this table.

The **menu_order** field should have a value, now if you knew where it was on a particular menu that will help.
 Also, the **post_content** field for any custom taxonomies will probably be blank, so that could be in indicator too. The other values in the **post_content** field should have the content of a particular post and these are probably not causing the problem.

it's better than deleting all of the database tables. It's worked for me.  try it, and let me know after that it works for you or not....

Comment: that error is'nt show in formatting,php.It shows in a template,where i put that code